# What is $t in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

First time ever working with `Vue.js` and have no clue what is `$t`. For instance I have someone's code like this:

```
 <li class="category-filter__back">
   <button
     class="category-filter__button"
     @click="back(categoryPath)">
     {{ $t(backButtonText) }} <<<<<<<< what is this $t?
   </button>
 </li>
```

Can't seem to find any concrete answer for this.

Comment: Vuex is a state management pattern for vue.js.`$t` is the injected method from vue.js or Vue.i18n.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It looks like a function for translations. Maybe that: http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n?

Answer (score 16):

$t here should be [an extended Vue instance method](http://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/directive.html#t) of Vue I18n.

Here is [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/jyougo/c1qt3h6y/) on jsfiddle:

**Template**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <!-- string literal -->
  <p v-t="'hello'"></p>

  <!-- keypath biniding via data -->
  <p v-t="path"></p>

  <!-- extended Vue instance method -->
  <p>{{ $t("wait") }}</p>

  <button @click="changeLocale()">
    {{ $t("buttonText") }}
  </button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  i18n: new VueI18n({
    locale: 'en',
    messages: {
      en: { hello: 'hi there', bye: 'see you later', wait: 'just a minute', buttonText: 'Change to Chinese Locale' },
      cn: { hello: '你好', bye: '再见', wait: '稍等一下', buttonText: '更改为英文场景' }
    }
  }),
  data: { path: 'bye' },
  methods: {
    changeLocale() {
        this.$i18n.locale = this.$i18n.locale === 'en' ? 'cn' : 'en'
    }
  }
})
```