# How to reference object prop from Vue3 template component

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3

I am updating a Vue2 to Vue3 application and I am facing a problem when referencing the xxxxx prop of the component1 from the parent one.

Here is the code

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'component1',

  props: {
    xxxxx: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Used by

```
 <li
    v-for="(value, index) in xxxxxs"
    :key="index">
    <benefit-item :benefit=value />
  </li>
```

where xxxxxs is an object collection loaded from a file

xxxxxs() {
return this.$t('pages.home.benefits.items')
}

The error shown in the console is

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "xxxxx". Expected Object, got
> String with value "p".

Looking at the documentation seems that the code is correct.
What I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: error itself says expected object and the value got is string. You have declared the proptype as object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you don't use here the `xxxxx` property.

```
<benefit-item :benefit=value />
```

At second, the `value` should be put in *quotes* or *double quotes*

```
<benefit-item :benefit='value' />
```

Assuming, that your property is used correctly, the problem is most likely with your data.

Do following in xxxxxs()

```
xxxxxs() { 
    let data = this.$t('pages.home.benefits.items');
    console.log(data);
    return data; 
}
```

and check the data.

**UPDATE**

You code is using [`t$` directive](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/directive.html#t), which is most likely part of the [Vue I18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/) plugin. If you have problem with the translation, check the plugin setup. Since we don't see your setup, it's not possible to clarify the problem with the translation.

Comment: Thanks. The data is loaded correctly, but where I call this.$t('pages.home.benefits.items'), the data variable just contains the string value 'pages.home.benefits.items'.

Comment: Check also this answer [What is $t in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52478092/what-is-t-in-vue-js)